# How to close Guide.BeginShowMessageBox from code

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm running an asynchronous web request on Windows Phone 7 and I want the user to be able to cancel the request when it takes too long. I show a message box by calling:

```
IAsyncResult result = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Synchronize", "Synchronizing with MyWebsite.com...", new string[] { "Cancel" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.None, OnEndDialog, null);
```

In the OnEndDialog callback I can cancel the request, which works fine.

But when the request is finished I want to close the message box from my code. Unfortunately, when I call

```
Guide.EndShowMessageBox(result);
```

from my code (yes, I use dispatcher.BeginInvoke to run the call on the UI thread), it turns out to be a blocking call and the dialog is still waiting for the user to press the Cancel button.

Is there any way to close the message box from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is not possible to close the Guide message box from code.

I solved the problem by using the MessagePrompt control from the [Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). You can call OnCompleted(...) to close the message box.

I added a Dismiss method to the base class (UserPrompt) which can be called from a background thread:

```
    public void Dismiss(PopUpResult result)
    {
        // Dismiss can be called from any thread. Make sure to execute on UI thread:
        Dispatcher dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            OnCompleted(new PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult> { PopUpResult = result });
        }
        else
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { Dismiss(result); }));
        }
    }
```